# redirection issue in javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, modal-dialog

I am new to php and javascript.I have written one modal dialog open script in 1st php file for new user account creation.after taking the valid input in the modal window I have sent the information to 2nd php page by post method to insert the data in database.

Now there is the issue.In the 2nd php page there is a method to check if the email address is already exist in database then show the error else insert the data into database and redirect to 3rd php page.

But not able to write the logic for the same.Please guide me to write the logic for if in the 2nd page the email check method returns true then show the error else after successfully inserting the data redirect to 3rd page.

Please find the code snippet below

2nd php and 3rd php are in same folder.the head() part is not working and need to show the error also for the 2nd page validation.
1st php most of the code is javascript and html form.from there i am doing the post to 2nd page

```
        **1st php**

 <script>       
                $("#dialog-form").dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    height: 300,
                    width: 350,
                    modal: true,
                    buttons: {
                        "Create an account": function() {
                            var bValid = true;
                            allFields.removeClass("ui-state-error");
                            bValid = bValid && checkLength(email, "email", 6, 80);
                            bValid = bValid && checkLength(password, "password", 5, 16);
                            bValid = bValid && checkLength(confirmpassword, "confirmpassword", 3, 16);
                            bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(email, .....);
                            bValid = bValid && checkRegexp(password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9");
                            bValid = bValid && IsEqual(password, confirmpassword, "password & confirmpassword are not equal");
                            if (bValid) {
                                $.ajax({
                                    type: "POST",
                                    url: "./create_account.php?act=create",
                                    data: "&email=" + email.val() + "&password=" + password.val() + "&confirmpassword=" + confirmpassword.val(),
                                    success: function(data) {

                                    }
                                });
                                $(this).dialog("close");
                            }
                        },
                        Cancel: function() {
                            $(this).dialog("close");
                        }
                    },
                    close: function() {
                        allFields.val("").removeClass("ui-state-error");
                    }
                });
                $("#create-user")
                        .button()
                        .click(function() {
                    $("#dialog-form").dialog("open");
                });
            });
        </script>
        <div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
            <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                    <label for="confirmpassword">confirm password</label>
                    <input type="password" name="confirmpassword" id="confirmpassword" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>


    **2nd php**

    <?php

    $action = $_GET['act'];

    if(!empty($_POST['email'])&&($_POST['password'])&&($_POST['confirmpassword'])) {


        $email_address = tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['email']);
        $password = tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['password']);
        $confirmpassword = tep_db_prepare_input($HTTP_POST_VARS['confirmpassword']);

        $error = false;

      {
            $db = new mysql("root", "", "modal_db", "localhost");
            $email_query_status ="select count(*) as total from " . CUSTOMERS . " where customers_email_address = $email_address ;
            $check_email = mysql($email_query_status );
            if ($check_email['total'] > 0) {
                $error = true;
            }
        }
        if ($error == false) {
            $db->query("INSERT INTO user_info SET customers_email_address ='$email_address', password='$pword'");
            header('Location: 3rd.php');


        }
    }
    ?>




        Thanks in advance, 

        Debasis
```

Comment: "Please let me know if you need any other information." Stackoverflow is not a place for questions like this at all, you should write code corresponding to your questions and ask us why it doesn't work. Google can probably solve 90% of the problem for you, if you need more help by not understanding code then you can ask us. It's, however, easy to see if something exists in a database, just select * from the database, if the result is false then it doesn't exist, otherwise it does. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/about

Answer (score 0):

"check if the email address is already exist in database then show the error else insert the data into database and redirect to 3rd php page."

- "SELECT * FROM table WHERE email = :email";
- If the result is true, then the email already exists and you can create the error message.
- If the result is false, then insert.
- You can then use

  header("Location: index.php");

To redirect with PHP.

Comment: What you actually mean is 'SELECT * FROM [table] WHERE email=?'

Comment: I have used header("Location: index.php"); but it is not working means redirecting.The modal dialog is closing and it keeps staying on the 1st page.

Comment: I know what I mean, @NickMitchinson, and thanks for the comment, I'm just saying that I have no idea what his table's name is so he can figure out the rest himself :) I think he should put some effort into his questions (code) before getting full working solutions. Now, Deba, are you in the same folder as index.php is? I can't tell you what's wrong until you post some code.

Comment: My point was just that you left out the WHERE clause, which was an extremely important part.

Comment: Thanks u both.I have updated some code from my project.please find it in my post.